# groovy, I want to know the meaning of the code

Tags: groovy, closures

I'm studying about groovy
I didn't understand this code
especially [list[0]]+getPairs(list[2..

```
    def getPairs(list) {
        if (list.size() < 2)
            []
        else {
            if (list[0]==list[1])
                [list[0]]+getPairs(list[2..<list.size()])
            else
                getPairs(list[1..<list.size()])
        }
    }
    println getPairs([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    println getPairs([1, 1, 2, 3, 3])
    println getPairs([1, 2, 2, 3, 3])

[]
[1.3]
[2,3]
```

Comment: What do you think it does?  Have you tried it out in the groovysh?

Comment: did you find some ancient manuscript?